# best rpm for most energy efficiency

Tags: cadence

What rpm when peddling is the most energy efficient aka least calories burned for the fastest speed?

Comment: depends on the person

Comment: Technically OP is only asking about energy efficiency, not how to obtain the highest power output for the longest duration ;)

Comment: The linked duplicate has the singular best answer ever seen on bicycles.SE.  Its well worth a detailed read.    One of the odd things about this site is that a lot of the more-common questions have been asked at some point, so the repository of knowledge already here is enormous.  Upshot, its worth browsing around the old questions.

Comment: The word is pedalling, people!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few studies which show that lower pedaling rate is more efficient (i.e. consumes less oxygen/fuel for the same power output):
[1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8970143/), [2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6978470_Relationship_between_efficiency_and_pedal_rate_in_cycling_Significance_of_internal_power_and_muscle_fiber_type_composition), [3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12758694_Cycling_efficiency_and_pedaling_frequency_in_road_cyclists)

However, it stands to reason that it’s more tiring for your muscles because they have to produce more force/torque to achieve the same power output.

I think your body is pretty good at picking the right cadence for the current circumstances. Most cyclists automatically pedal at around 90rpm when riding at moderate or high intensity. That being said, I think it can still make sense to train at very low or high cadence from time to time. It’s also a good idea to have the right gear range and gear steps for the terrain you are riding.

Comment: It might be worth moving this answer over to the linked duplicate question - your call.